# Why Bluetooth 2 use pi/4-DQPSK instead of OQPSK?

Tags: digital-communications, power-spectral-density, phase, modulation, qpsk

From the peak to average power ratio point of view OQPSK is better than pi/4-DQPSK. What is the advantage of pi/4-DQPSK compare to OQPSK? Why Bluetooth 2 use pi/4-DQPSK instead of OQPSK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One particular advantage of pi/4 QPSK and pi/4 DQPSK is that there is always a transition between symbols, making demodulation simpler. Differential - PSK (such as DQPSK) can be demodulated without a local oscillator (by comparing previous symbols to the current ones), making for extremely low cost receivers at a modest expense in performance (sensitivity).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't understand your comment "that there is always a transition between symbols, making demodulation simpler" Could you explain this part easily?

Comment: @agile Observe the state transitions for pi/4 QPSK and compare that to OQPSK. Every other symbol in pi/4 QPSK moves to another 4 point constellation that is completely rotated by 45 degrees, thus forcing a transition. With OQPSK  in contrast it is possible that you stay on the same location in the constellation over multiple symbols.

Comment: I already know what you said. But I don't understand why that thing simplifies the demodulation.

Comment: If you are guaranteed a transition on every symbol it simplifies doing timing recovery.

Comment: Now I understand.^^ Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, with the omnipresence of scrambling techniques, I think it is very rare that signals stay in the same location of the constellation over many consecutive symbols. I wonder if there is any other advantage?

Comment: @AlexTP even with scrambling you can still have runs with the same location- so I go to say that timing recovery is extremely simple in that no recovery loop is actually needed